# Coordinate geometry diagonals.

Tags: analytic-geometry

The diagonals of a parallelogram $PQRS$ are $$x+3y=4$$ and $$6x-2y=7$$ Now this is pretty clear that the two diagonals are perpendicular to each other and hence it can be a square or a rhombus. But how do I decide whether its actually a square of a rhombus. (I am asking this because the question which I solved had both square and rhombus as its option).

Comment: They are infinite lines, you need further information.

Comment: you probably need know one side or other details.